# Search word in CSV and replace with tag

Tags: c#, html, csv, razor, umbraco

In Umbraco I have made a field (supportListItemWordMarking) to input a csv of words that the user want to have highlighted in a header, f.x.

```
This is a very fine header
```

And the user want to have `very` and `header` highlighted with red

The field in umbraco will then look like this:

very,header

I am trying to make a razor script so that it will look in the header for words inputted in the `supportListItemWordMarking` field and then output something like this:

```
<h1>This is a <span class="red">very</span> fine <span class="red">header</span></h1>
```

I have come up with this:

```
  @{
     if(subItem.HasValue("supportListItemWordMarking")) {
        string[] wordMarking = subItem.GetValue("supportListItemWordMarking").ToString().Split(',');                                        
       }
   }
```

But I am not sure if this is the right approach, so I am stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably how I would do it:

```
var txt = "This is a very fine header";

var wordMarking = new string[] { "very", "header" };

// search for all words using regex
var rx = new Regex(@"(\w+)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

// the text to replace all regex matches with
// any words found will be inserted into {0} using string.Format
var replacementText = "<span class=\"red\">{0}</span>";

var newTxt = rx.Replace(txt, (match) =>
{
    var wordFound = match.Groups[1].Value;

    // check if word should be marked
    if (wordMarking.Contains(wordFound))
    {
        // return the new word with the replacement
        return string.Format(replacementText, wordFound);
    }

    return wordFound;
});
```

If the list `wordMarking` has many items, then you should use a dictionary to improve performance.